# Vanilla JS + jQuery click functions to return specified values from nested array data: How to redraft click events into conditional value returns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

https://codepen.io/bloomscode/pen/MWpRewv

jQuery came up among Bootstrap interests for an exercise I'm expanding before getting more into the React framework. The app's Codepen is linked above. I'm editing this post because I've made progress on adding button controls for the app to select in designated areas of the nested array (it had to do with where the curly brace closes, seeing how much stayed within the encompassing function, for it to make the informed transformations.)

Do click events with either jQuery or vanilla JS more ideally involve conditionals, based on what's clicked, whereby we can loop through the array to establish how each of these functions will pull from the next index of data? I am looking to cut repeat code in another application that handles early literacy data, and it seems a loop or `map` function may aid that as in this smaller example, and I'm not encountering frequent use examples that don't just build atop of larger generalized API data.

```
 $(".quote-text").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200, function () {
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200);
    $("#text").text(currentQuote);
  });

  $(".quote-author").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200, function () {
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200);
    $("#author").text(currentAuthor);
  });
```

As an example, here is a sample code snippet that determines both `currentQuote` and `currentAuthor` values at a given time.

```
function getRandomComfort() {
  return quotes[2][Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes[2].length)];
}

function getComfort() {
  randomQuote = getRandomComfort();
  currentQuote = randomQuote[0];
  currentAuthor = randomQuote[1];
```

Comment: You should be assigning a _reference_ to the click listeners rather than the _results_ of calling those functions. `$("#new-quote").on("click", getInspo);`.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. I updated the reference so it added the click event for the first button only, and it ended up the build of the functions needed to include the jQuery change mechanisms (curly brace needed to enclose that `.animate` and `.text` logic for the specificities to be called in fully even by reference. I adjusted that, all the buttons are doing their things! -- and yet the `#author` field is no longer populating any "currentAuthor" values lol, so I updated where those mods leave it, if you happen to see something glaring.

Comment: @JessRenard span with `id` author has a whitespace in the id name. That's why the element `$("#author")` is undefined. Remove the whitespace in the id attribute

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks very much. I just modified this question again lol, because I'm cringing at approaching the functions with so much redundancy. Would conditionals, loops, or `map` be a better outlook on pairing up any of this data? Asking for interests of a larger dataset...